# Elasticsearch on GKE - Unable to configure snapshot and restore using gcs plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, elasticsearch-plugin

We are setting up an ES cluster on GKE in the following format:

1. Master nodes as kubernetes deployments
2. Client nodes as kubernetes deployments with HPA
3. Data nodes as stateful sets with PVs

We are able to set up the cluster well. But then we are struggling in configuring the snapshot backup mechanism. Essentially, we are following [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/repository-gcs-usage.html) guide. We are able to follow this upto the step of getting the secret json key. Afterwards, we are not sure how to add this to the elasticsearch keystore and proceed further. Would be great if someone can help us out with this

Answer (score 0):

In IAM & admin > Service Accounts, click on Create Service Account put the name you wish and click Create, then in Role select "Storage Admin" for example and then click Continue, then click Done.

After that on the on the Service Accounts section, click on the 3 dots of the Service Account you create and select "Create key" > JSON > Create

This will generate/download the JSON file.

Then you need to storage this key in the Elasticsearch keystore.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/secure-settings.html